# How to get "Total" Disk read/writes per process in ubuntu from terminal command?

Tags: disk, monitor, io

How to get "Total" Disk read/writes per-process in ubuntu using the command line?

or "How to get all parameter values of system monitor using a command line like using top command or so per second."

I am able to get per-process disk I/O speeds. but I also need total Disk read/write per-process as it's visible in system monitor screenshot.

[System Monitoring Screenshot parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVL67.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One you can try is `iotop`

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install iotop
```

Then just run `sudo iotop`

```
Total DISK READ :       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :     894.43 K/s
Actual DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Actual DISK WRITE:     925.27 K/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND          
  497 be/3 root        0.00 B/s   65.54 K/s  0.00 %  1.05 % [jbd2/dm-1-8]
21539 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.25 % [kworker/~s_unbound]
22873 be/4 terrance    0.00 B/s   15.42 K/s  0.00 %  0.02 % firefox [~T~s #2451]
 9991 be/4 terrance    0.00 B/s  813.47 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % firefox [DOM Worker]
    1 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % init splash
    2 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kthreadd]
    3 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_gp]
    4 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_par_gp]
    6 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/~s_highpri]
    8 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [mm_percpu_wq]
    9 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/0]
   10 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_sched]
   11 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/0]
   12 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [idle_inject/0]
   14 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [cpuhp/0]
   15 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [cpuhp/1]
   16 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [idle_inject/1]
   17 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/1]
   18 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/1]
   20 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/~s_highpri]
   21 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [cpuhp/2]
```

If you want to see Total since `iotop` started per process use `-a` for accumulate:

```
sudo iotop -a


Total DISK READ :       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :       0.00 B/s
Actual DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Actual DISK WRITE:       0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND          
  464 be/3 root          0.00 B    940.00 K  0.00 %  0.12 % [jbd2/sde1-8]
31167 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.11 % [kworker/~le_power_]
 1689 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.10 % [kworker/~s_unbound]
31999 be/4 terrance      0.00 B      2.72 M  0.00 %  0.02 % firefox [~torage #1]
 1541 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.01 % [kworker/~s_unbound]
32119 be/4 terrance      0.00 B    528.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % firefox [~torage #9]
32060 be/4 terrance      0.00 B    264.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % firefox [~torage #4]
32006 be/4 terrance      0.00 B    196.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % firefox [~torage DB]
32005 be/4 terrance      0.00 B    132.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % firefox [DOM Worker]
31939 be/4 terrance     12.00 K    820.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % firefox [Cache2 I/O]
  527 be/3 root          0.00 B     44.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % systemd-journald
 2764 be/4 mongodb       0.00 B    284.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % mongod --~onf [ftdc]
31992 be/4 terrance      0.00 B     56.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % firefox [~taStorage]
32116 be/4 terrance      0.00 B    872.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % firefox [~torage #8]
    1 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % init nosplash
    2 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [kthreadd]
    3 be/0 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_gp]
    4 be/0 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_par_gp]
    6 be/0 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/~H-kblockd]
    8 be/0 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [mm_percpu_wq]
    9 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/0]
```

To get more options check the manpage

```
man iotop
```

Comment: But this does not include per process Total Disk Read/Write as shown in the system monitor screenshot.

Comment: @Mayank90 If you run it with the `-a` it does, but this is only showing since it started running `iotop`.  Edited to show

Comment: Thanks. I run it and -a gives the total read and write in the place of earlier read/write speed column. I was expecting different columns as visible in the ubuntu System monitor. so to get speed per sec, I will have to run a separate thread in this case.